# Saving firebase data to variable swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so this has been something that I have been trying to work out for a while, both by myself and searching through stack overflow. I am using swift with firebase to record the amount of likes a certain "post" has. What I need to do, is set the amount of likes, which is a label, to the number of likes in firebase. I have firebase all set up and connected with my project, and this is what I have so far.

```
   @IBAction func one_1(sender: AnyObject) {
    if un_1.textColor == UIColor.blueColor() {
        ref.child("IssueLikes").child("Abortion").child("Upvotes").setValue("\(Int(un_1.text!)! + 1)")
        ref.child("IssueLikes").child("Abortion").child("Downvotes").setValue("\(Int(un_2.text!)! - 1)")
        un_1.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        un_2.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    } else if un_1.textColor == UIColor.whiteColor() {
        un_2.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        // SET LABEL TO  ref.child("IssueLikes").child("Abortion").child("Downvotes") VALUE

    }
}
```

I have found nothing on how I can do this, and any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the down votes value so when it changes, your label is automatically updated.

```
ref.child("IssueLikes/Abortion/Downvotes").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { [weak self] snapshot in
    self?.un_2.text = snapshot.value as? String
})
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, however I am getting an error saying that 'Value of type 'FirDatabaseReference' has no member 'observe''

Comment: I've updated my answer, I wrote it for Swift 3 buy you're not using that

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be responding to the changes in firebase. I also tried to set the event type to .ChildChanged, but that is not working either.